# Tensorflow RNN tutorial

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am following [RNN tutorial of Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent). 
I am having trouble understanding the `function ptb_producer` in `reader.py` in following script :

```
    with tf.control_dependencies([assertion]):
      epoch_size = tf.identity(epoch_size, name="epoch_size")

    i = tf.train.range_input_producer(epoch_size, shuffle=False).dequeue()
    x = tf.strided_slice(data, [0, i * num_steps],[batch_size, (i + 1) * num_steps])
    x.set_shape([batch_size, num_steps])
    y = tf.strided_slice(data, [0, i * num_steps + 1],[batch_size, (i + 1) * num_steps + 1])
    y.set_shape([batch_size, num_steps])
    return x, y
```

Can anyone explain what `tf.train.range_input_producer` is doing ?

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to understand the same tutorial for weeks now. In my opinion, what makes it so difficult is the fact that all the functions one calls from TensorFlow are not executed immediately, but rather add their corresponding operation nodes to the graph.

According to the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_docs/python/tf/train/range_input_producer), a Range Input Producer 'generates integers from `0` to `limit - 1` in a queue'. So, the way I see it, the code in question `i = tf.train.range_input_producer(epoch_size, shuffle=False).dequeue()` creates a node, which acts as a counter, producing the next number in the sequence `0:(epoch_size)` once executed.

This is used to get the next batch from the input data. The raw data is split into `batch_size` rows, so that in every run `batch_size` batches are given to the training function. In every batch (row), a sliding window of size `num_steps` moves forward. The counter `i` allows the window to move forward by `num_steps` in every call.

Both `x` and `y` are of shape `[batch_size, num_steps]`, since they contain `batch_size` batches of `num_steps` steps each. Variable `x` is the input and `y` is the expected output for the given input (it is produced by moving the window one item to the left, so that `iff x = data[i:(i + num_steps] then y = data[(i + 1):(i + num_steps + 1)]`.

It has been a nightmare for me, but I hope this post helps people in the future.